# Mysql - Only rows that value from one column matches for all from other column

Tags: mysql, sql

I never asked here because I always had in my mind that Google Skills are better than bothering people around... And I couldn't find it anywhere... Maybe my google skills are not that good, then... But I really don't know how to get this thing done.

Picture the above:

```
DELIVER_METHOD_CODE | PRODUCT_CODE
1                   | 909
1                   | 4
2                   | 4
```

I just need the values from the first column when they match for ALL values from the socond column...

Does anyone out there know how to do it? D;

For getting this far my query is like that:

```
select DELIVER_METHOD_CODE,PRODUCT_CODE
from DELIVER_METHOD_TABLE
right join PRODUCT_TABLE on PRODUCT_TABLE.PRODUCT_ID = DELIVER_METHOD_TABLE.PRODUCT_ID
```

Sorry for bad English

EDIT1:

How the output should be

```
DELIVER_METHOD_CODE | PRODUCT_CODE
1                   | 909
1                   | 4
```

Comment: Can you please give the output you're expecting for this example input?

Comment: Sorry... I had forgotten. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of a "set-within-sets" subquery.  I think the most flexible approach is to use aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
select DELIVER_METHOD_CODE
from DELIVER_METHOD_TABLE
group by DELIVER_METHOD_CODE
having count(distinct PRODUCT_CODE) = (select count(distinct PRODUCT_CODE)
                                       from DELIVER_METHOD_TABLE
                                      );
```